# .webm file is safe to delete for virtualbox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I used ubuntu in virtualbox and allocated memory dynamicaly.
 i am getting low memory disk in host system because of .webm file of virtual box. i have not much idea about .webm file but it took around 50GB space so is it safe to delete that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution for .webm file. it was just video capturing and yes i removed all .webm file which consume around 50GB data. and it will not affect if you removed it from virtualbox.